# Подсказка в intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse, ide

Подскажите пожалуйста, как настроить в intellij idea такие же подсказки как в Eclipse?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я разобрался с данным вопросом.

Во первых, это называется не подсказка. а Quick Documentation.

Если вы хотите видеть больше информации о выражении под курсором (откуда оно вызывается, его тип или другую дополнительную информацию), вам поможет Quick Documentation. Нажмите Ctrl+Q для Windows (Ctrl+J для OS X), чтобы активировать его и вы увидите всплывающее окно с данными. Если вам не нужна полная информация, используйте Type Info: он показывает только тип выбранного выражения, но не занимает столько места на экране. Для вызова Type Info необходимо зажать Ctrl и навести курсором на интересующий фрагмент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же Quick Documentation можно настроить при наведении курсором.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как этот TypeInfo вызывать?

Comment: Зажать Ctrl и навести курсор на интересующий фрагмент