# как влючить быструю документацию (подсказки) в intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

как влючить быструю документацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы не при нажатии клавиш выскакивала подсказка, а автоматически?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нашёл ответ 2х годичной давности
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003696/Подсказка-в-intellij-idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003696/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-intellij-idea)
раньше этот пункт был в settings > editor > general -----> show quick documentation on mouth move

ковырялся, так и не смог найти в настройках

Comment: На стандартных настройках работает при наведении курсора :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editor > General > Code Editting > Quick Documentation > show quick documentation on mouth move

навести на элемент, нажать ctrl+q и выбрать пункт в меню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]